# OpenCV and Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I have installed the latest versions of `OpenCV` and `Eclipse CDT`, but not able to make OpenCV to be used within Eclipse CDT.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually setup Eclipse.

Check this [blog post](http://www.jestinstoffel.com/?q=node/112).

Comment: header location is moved to `/usr/local/include/opencv2`, global header is `opencv.hpp` not `cv.h`, and libs are renamed to `opencv_core`, `opencv_ml` etc.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe @user588855 is still using version <= 2.1

Comment: I'm using the *latest* versions of `OpenCV` and `Eclipse CDT` under Windows 7 but not able to get working together.

Comment: @karlphillip. I have seen the blog post you mentioned, but have some issues with. For example, the blog post has a step where selected is `Manage Make C++ Project`, which I don't have, and from here the issue started. Also, there is a step where Directories are selected under GCC C++ Complier, and the case is that I don't have directories, and the compiler is Cygwin C++ Compiler. Maybe this is due version differences

Comment: I'll try that later on my Win 7 laptop and will come back here with more info.