# OpenCV and Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have installed the latest versions of `OpenCV` and `Eclipse CDT`, but not able to make OpenCV to be used within Eclipse CDT.

Any ideas on how can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably better to ask on stackoverflow.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV and Eclipse CDT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140662/opencv-and-eclipse-cdt)

Answer (score 1):

What platform?

See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/EclipseOpenCVLinux ?

Otherwise you generally run cmake in the top of the opencv source dir and select the compiler you want, for Eclipse that's possibly mingw (unless there is an eclipse specific version)